# Response Header too large - Jetty Embedded version 9

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I'm getting an exception of "Response Header too large" when using Jetty, the exception is thrown at the Client and only when the size of the `jsonValue` is large (greater than 1500 bytes). If the `jsonvalue` is smaller, everything works fine.

This is the code I have, it is very simple.

Server Code:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
ServletHandler handler = new ServletHandler();
server.setHandler(handler);

handler.addServletWithMapping(StoreServlet.class, "/store");

server.start();
server.join();
```

StoreServlet class code:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    response.getWriter().println("<h1>Store SimpleServlet</h1>");
}
```

Client Code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.start();

ContentResponse response = httpClient.POST("http://0.0.0.0:" + host.getPort() + "/store").param("p", jsonValue).send();
```

StactTrace:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Response header too large
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.getResult(FutureResponseListener.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.util.FutureResponseListener.get(FutureResponseListener.java:101)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:589)
    at com.paywithbytes.communication.http.client.HttpClientHelper.doPost(HttpClientHelper.java:54)
    at com.paywithbytes.communication.http.client.HttpClientHelper.main(HttpClientHelper.java:35)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Response header too large
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateRequest(HttpGenerator.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpSenderOverHTTP.sendHeaders(HttpSenderOverHTTP.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.send(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP$Delegate.send(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.send(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpDestinationOverHTTP.send(HttpDestinationOverHTTP.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpDestinationOverHTTP.send(HttpDestinationOverHTTP.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.PoolingHttpDestination$2.run(PoolingHttpDestination.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:536)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.nio.BufferOverflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:183)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:832)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateRequestLine(HttpGenerator.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateRequest(HttpGenerator.java:218)
    ... 11 more
```

The answer selected was perfect, I just want to add that when sending a large file it is better to use this method:

```
Request request = httpClient.POST("http://0.0.0.0:" + host.getPort() + "/store").content(
            new BytesContentProvider(jsonValue.getBytes()), "text/plain");
```

Otherwise, if sending a large `jsonValue` as a `POST param`, you will get:

```
414 Request-URI Too Long
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using maven jetty plugin version: 9.1.3.v20140225**

You are going to need a custom value for your "request buffer size". By default it is 4096 bytes.

You can use the method setRequestBufferSize of the HttpClient class (see javadoc: [org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/client/HttpClient.html))

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.setRequestBufferSize(/*your custom value*/);
httpClient.start();

ContentResponse response = httpClient.POST("http://0.0.0.0:" + host.getPort() + "/store").param("p", jsonValue).send();
```

Your custom value will depend on how many bytes you are sending plus a few more, which are always sent by the HTTP client implementation. For example, in my case and using the above code I am sending the following:

```
POST /?p=YOUR_JSON_VALUE HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080/store
User-Agent: Jetty/9.1.3.v20140225
```

Comment: thanks @Gooseman! I missed that, I was thinking that the problem could have been in the server side.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into a problem with seemingly the same symptoms but a different cause. In my case, I was trying to post messages containing 3MB of data to a servlet. Increasing the request buffer size did not resolve the problem.

The problem turned out that I was reusing the same request object instead of making a new request object per actual request.