# "Request header too large" when opening WebSocket request

Tags: websocket, jetty

I am connecting a WebSocket client to a URI with a very long query parameter, as follows:

```
WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
URI uri = getVeryLongUri();
WebSocketListener websocketListener = getEventListener9);
client.connect(websocketListener, uri);
```

Using Jetty 9.4.8.v20171121 I get:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: 0 null
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketUpgradeRequest.onComplete(WebSocketUpgradeRequest.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.abort(HttpReceiver.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpChannel.abortResponse(HttpChannel.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.terminateRequest(HttpSender.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.abort(HttpSender.java:561)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.anyToFailure(HttpSender.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender$CommitCallback.failed(HttpSender.java:712)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpSenderOverHTTP$HeadersCallback.failed(HttpSenderOverHTTP.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpSenderOverHTTP.sendHeaders(HttpSenderOverHTTP.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.send(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:199)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP$Delegate.send(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.send(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpDestinationOverHTTP.send(HttpDestinationOverHTTP.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.process(HttpDestination.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.process(HttpDestination.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.send(HttpDestination.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpDestination.succeeded(HttpDestination.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractConnectionPool.proceed(AbstractConnectionPool.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractConnectionPool$1.succeeded(AbstractConnectionPool.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractConnectionPool$1.succeeded(AbstractConnectionPool.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Promise$Wrapper.succeeded(Promise.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onOpen(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onOpen(SslConnection.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.connectionOpened(SelectorManager.java:322)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(ManagedSelector.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1600(ManagedSelector.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run(ManagedSelector.java:650)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Request header too large
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateRequest(HttpGenerator.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpSenderOverHTTP$HeadersCallback.process(HttpSenderOverHTTP.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.BufferOverflowException: null
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:189)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:859)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateRequestLine(HttpGenerator.java:574)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateRequest(HttpGenerator.java:253)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22472794/14731 mentions that for normal HTTP clients the request buffer size has to be increased, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent configuration option for WebSocket clients. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You need to pass a custom `HttpClient` into the `WebSocketClient` constructor.

```
WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
client.getHttpClient().setRequestBufferSize(...);
```

Comment: A huge URI is a code-smell / anti-pattern.   Consider putting whatever is in that URI into the websocket messaging instead.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt Agreed but I am consuming a [3rd party API](https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-official-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md) (section "combined streams") so I don't have much choice in the matter.

Comment: Alrighty then, just keep this statement in mind if you find yourself troubleshooting connection issues through various intermediaries (gateways, firewalls, load balancers, routers, etc...).  That huge URL is the most likely cause of not getting through those problematic devices.